# Android SQLite call retrieves all values except REAL

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have been looking at the code for hours without finding what is at fault. I need second and third eyes on it. It's probably something obvious.

I even tried to write a separate function to collect the data and that too is failing.

The code to collect the data looks like this:

```
    public double getHeight(){
    double height = 0;

    String querySettings = "SELECT " +
        KEY_USER_SETTINGS_HEIGHT +
        " FROM " + TABLE_USER_SETTINGS + " WHERE _id = 1;";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(querySettings, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        height = cursor.getDouble(0);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return height;
  }
```

The cursor string looks like this:

```
SELECT height FROM user_settings WHERE _id = 1;
```

Running it, on the exactly same database, in a separate client such as DB Browser renders the following result:

```
186.0
```

Running the exact same query in the app gives me:

```
0.0
```

I have a larger function that collects all kinds of data and it all gets collected. They are all int and they get retried. This is the only one that does not work. There are no errors in logcat.

What obvious thing am i missing?

**UPDATE 1**
@Mike _id = 1 exists and is being used since i get the other data in that row. The database is copied out from the virtual device. Even when i don't specify row and take "all rows" (only 1 row exists there) the same thing happens.

@Diego mCount = 1

Comment: Id = **1**, **1** probably isn't a row in the table. add `else { Log.d("Ouchh!!!!","No row found for ID = 1");}`. Exactly the same database???, **unlikely**, very likely a **similar** database.

Comment: set a breakpoint inside the loop or log `cursor.getCount()` to check how many rows are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have much more time to put on searching for what went wrong so i tried to recreate the entire database. That solved it. Very odd. I have worked with databases for many years and this has never happened to me before.

The code is the same but now it works. The exact nature of the fault is still unknown. Either a bug or something i did wrong. Only 1 column of 1 row being faulty. Even if i did a "SELECT * FROM user_settings" that height would only return 0.0. All other columns in that row returned data correctly.

Thank you for the help though guys.